# How do you get to level 36 in Candy Crush Saga?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

After half a weekend spent on conquering Candy Crush Saga levels, I have finally arrived at level 36. Unfortunately, there seems to be a "barrier" of sorts to start playing this level, with two options:

1. Ask your Facebook friends for help
2. Buy a ticket for $0.99

While option #2 is extremely cheap, I'm curious what option #1 entails. I am personally extremely annoyed when I get enormous amounts of requests from Facebook applications and I don't want to annoy my friends this way. While I know selecting option #1 sends a request to my Facebook friends, what happens after that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you ask your Facebook friends, they'll be prompted to play the game.  If they refuse or have blocked the app, you won't get the ticket.  If they play, (I believe) they can give you one ticket towards each ticket checkpoint without any impact to their game.

In addition to spamming your friends and spending real money, you can also earn free tickets by replaying levels from the previous set in so-called "**[Mystery Quests](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/unlocking-new-episodes-in-candy-crush-saga-mystery-quests/)**".

**Update December 2014:**  You must be *completely offline* (ie, no 3G/4G/WiFi) in order to see Mystery Quests, now that King has added the "Kingdoms" feature to Candy Crush Saga.  It is no longer enough to log out of Facebook!

After passing a quest, you must wait *24 hours* before you can try the next.  I've heard multiple people mention that you can skip the wait by modifying your device's clock.  There's a particularly complete description of how to do this in [a comment here](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/candy-crush-saga-tricks-tips-and-guide/#comment-10442).

Once you've cleared the three bonus levels, you'll be allowed to continue.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the bonus levels. They probably purposefully hid that option since it has the least potential to get revenue ;)

Comment: @rikitikitik, yeah, I kind of stumbled upon it by accident.  I just mashed all the buttons.  I was not about to spam my FB friends or give them a dollar... :P

Comment: Just to add: I had trouble looking for the button that you mentioned where you can solve puzzles instead. However, when I took my iPad away from the Internet (no wifi, airplane mode), the third option now appears.

Comment: @rikitikitik Yeah, it's ridiculous. That option is *hidden* until you take the device offline or unlink your Facebook account.

Comment: Just to add: Android version gives the option for quests online and offline.

Comment: If you advance the date on your iPad by one day at the end of each level, you can play the second and third quests straight away

Comment: @Halfwarr yeah, also the UI for this feature got A LOT more obvious. Dunno if it's the same on the iOS interface, but agent's continued allowance of my existence hints it is.

Comment: I haven't been back to another ticket checkpoint (although I'm coming up on one) so I'll grab a screenshot if I do.

Comment: Instead of waiting 24hrs between quests you can fool the game by advancing your tablet clock by 1 day each time. You can also fool it by advancing the clock to get lives quicker.

Comment: @Nala I did that once; once I rolled time back I found myself with 0 lives and the next being granted in 1 day 30 minutes.

Comment: How to advance the time properly (checked on Android): (1) go to system clock, advance the day (it was simpler for me); (2) switch back to Candy Crush, note the new lives; (3) switch back to clock and turn date back; (4) switch to Candy Crush, new lives will stay there. Note, if switching took you more than a certain time (say, half a minute), Candy Crush app may get unloaded so it forgets the new lives. In this case, repeat from beginning.

Comment: @Halfwarr The Android version is the exact same as the iOS version. Both won't give you the quest option if you have both a linked Facebook account and Internet access.

Comment: @lunboks O got it I did not have a linked facebook.

Answer (score 1):

According to:

> http://www.chaptercheats.com/qna/ipad/112075/Candy-Crush-Saga-Answers.htm?qid=31432

You will need three friends to help you actually get the ticket to advance to level 36.

In other words, onc eyou click the Ask your Facebook friends for help, it would likely either send a message to a number of friends of your choosing or post it on your wall for your friends to click on it.

Comment: Yup, I know that a message/request will be sent to your friends as I mentioned in the question, but what happens after that? What are your friends supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You only need 3 friends to respond and actually after selecting option #1, you have select list where you can pick to which friends the request will be sent. So it isn't like you're going to spam all your friends with the request.

To help you your friends have to actually open the game. Request for help pop-up before actual gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait 3 days and the *Tooth fairy* will unlock the next episode.